# Convert parsed object to class instance

Tags: javascript, oop, local-storage

I know I can't store class instances with methods when stringified and parsed in able to put it in localstorage, so I just re-initialized it every time I got it from localstorage.

```
var savedtasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"))
if(savedtasks != null){
    for(var i=0; i < savedtasks.length; i++){
        var newtask = new Task(savedtasks[i].title, savedtasks[i].description, savedtasks[i].category, savedtasks[i].due)
        tasks.push(newtask)
        showTask(i)
    }

    $('#example').hide()
}
```

Instead of using the constructor every time, is there a more efficient way to just directly convert all the values of `savedtasks[i]` to a `Task`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `plainToClass` function of `class-transformer` package

https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#plaintoclass